# Geographical load balancing for Joomla website hosted on Azure Linux Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, joomla, centos, load-balancing, cdn

I'm hosting my Joomla website in a Linux CentOS 7 Azure VM, SEA region. Since my site is about video streaming, I need to set up geographical load balancing for my site to reduce the response time.
I can create the new VMs in US or EU region, but I don't know how to set up the geo load balancing for them (using Azure service or Joomla service). Could anyone help me?

Comment: Have you looked at the Traffic Manager service? http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/traffic-manager/

Comment: Already but it require some cloud services and I got stuck at setting up